# GridSearchCV for a Keras model: 'Functional' object has no attribute 'predict_classes'

Tags: python, keras, scikit-learn, attributeerror, grid-search

I built a neural network for multilabel classification that is working fine.

1. My training set features are gene expression level. They are `floats`
2. The targets are the molecular pathway associated with the gene expression. They are binary `0/1`.
3. The prediction of the neural network is the probability of a molecular pathway to be activated given the gene expression.

My problem is that for hyperparameter tuning, I am using `sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV` but keep getting the aforementioned error.

Here is a reproducible code:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from tensorflow.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf

#some datas
train = np.random.random((10,20))
target = np.random.binomial(1, 0.1,(10,5))

# Build the model
def create_model(): 
    inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(20,))
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(400, activation=tf.nn.relu)(inputs)
    outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid)(x)
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer= 'Adam')
    return model

model = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model, verbose=1)

param_grid = {'epochs':[10,20],
              'batch_size':[200],}

gs = GridSearchCV(
    estimator=model,
    param_grid=param_grid, 
    cv=3, 
    n_jobs=-1, 
    scoring= 'accuracy',
    verbose=2,
    )

fitted = gs.fit(train, target)
```

The error is the following, caused by the line `fitted = gs.fit(train, target)`

```
AttributeError: 'Functional' object has no attribute 'predict_classes'
```

Can anyone give me a clue?

Comment: Concerning your **EDIT**: please do not ask several questions in one. If you encounter several issues please debug sequentially and open one question per issue.

Comment: OK but It is not really to ask a new question: I thought that it could be a clue on the origin of the error, that is why I included it .

Comment: OK, I deleted all references to the different error message depending on the environment used.

Answer (score 1):

`'Functional' object has no attribute 'predict_classes'` indeed. 'predict_classes' only available for `Sequential` model. For your code to work you need to adapt it for multiclass proba predictions like:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from tensorflow.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf

#some datas
train = np.random.random((10,20))
target = np.random.binomial(1, 0.1,(10,5))

# Build the model
def create_model(): 
    inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(20,))
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(400, activation=tf.nn.relu)(inputs)
    outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation=tf.nn.softmax)(x)
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer= 'Adam')
    return model

model = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model, verbose=1)

param_grid = {'epochs':[10,20],
              'batch_size':[200],}

gs = GridSearchCV(
    estimator=model,
    param_grid=param_grid, 
    cv=3, 
    n_jobs=-1,
    verbose=2,
    )

fitted = gs.fit(train, target)
```

Then you're fine to go.

Output:

---

```
fitting 3 folds for each of 2 candidates, totalling 6 fits
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Using backend LokyBackend with 12 concurrent workers.
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done   3 out of   6 | elapsed:    2.3s remaining:    2.3s
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done   6 out of   6 | elapsed:    2.3s finished
Epoch 1/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 191ms/step - loss: 1.5599
Epoch 2/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 1.5250
Epoch 3/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 1.4932
Epoch 4/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 1.4649
Epoch 5/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 1.4396
Epoch 6/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 1.4165
Epoch 7/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 1.3950
Epoch 8/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 1.3746
Epoch 9/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 1.3553
Epoch 10/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 1.3370
```

Comment: It is working, but I don't understand clearly why: You changed the loss function to `'categorical_crossentropy'`, the last activation to `softmax'` and deleted the `'accuracy'`metric. How did that change the model to `Sequential`?

Comment: @onthemoon01 It did not. It's still functional. But conforms to the rules/expected tensor shapes of Functional API.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, I played with the parameters and found that I only had to move the `metrics = ['accuracy']` from the `GridSearchCV` parameters to the `model.compile`parameters. It seems that giving a metric to the `GridSearchCV` instance turned it into a functional model. So I can keep the `sigmoid`as output activation function which is better for my model.

Comment: @onthemoon01 It does not work the way you want it. Try recompiling your model from scratch (or reload your notebook) and see my answer